# Sybase - way to get time since ASE started?

Tags: sap-ase

Is there a way on Sybase ASE to get the time since the ASE server was started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a global variable **@@boottime** which can be used to find the time when the ASE server was started. Simply use -

**select @@boottime** to get the time when the server was started.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about ASE server uptime; if yes, then probably you can find so using the query

```
select crdate from master..sysdatabases where name = 'tempdb'
```

which will return the boot time, as `tempdb` is recreated at boot.